# Unit Test Coverage is being pedantic

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, test-coverage

I'm using the *Analyse Code Coverage* tool in *Visual Studio 2012*.  The report appears to be very pedantic about what is covered and I have no idea what else could be done to provide more coverage.

The code I am testing is this:

```
public class Factory<T> : IFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    public T Create()
    {
        return new T();  // This line has only partial coverage.
    }
}
```

The unit tests:

```
using System;
using Xunit;
public class Factory_Tests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Constructor_Works()
    {
        var target = new Factory<Exception>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Create_ReturnsNewValue()
    {
        var target = new Factory<Exception>();
        var actual = target.Create();
        Assert.NotNull(actual);
    }
}
```

The report claims that the line commented above has only partial coverage.  What could I have possibly failed to test on this line?

Comment: I would guess that due to it being generic, you haven't tested it with all the type of types that are allowed--i.e. you used a reference type, perhaps it wants you to use a value type as well.

Comment: I don't know C#, but isn't it pretty useless to simple check whether a method does not return null?

Comment: @MattSmith, yup, you've got it.  Thanks!

Comment: @NiklasB., not if the method guarantees it returns a value and returning null would cause a NullReferenceException elsewhere.  Yes, this is a very mundane test for a very mundane piece of code.  It's a personal exercise in not being test-lazy.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food Okay, but won't you test the *functionality* of the created object somewhere? That would certainly catch the NPE as well :) Anyway, it's not important for the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a generic method that can accept both a reference type and a value type, it wants you test it with both.